# Get/Set from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, get, set

I'm working on a project to translate a c# project to Java. I have the following Get/Set block in C#

```
 public Unit[] Units
{
    get
    {
        Unit[] units_aux = new Unit[this.list_units.Count];
        this.list_units.CopyTo(units_aux);
        return units_aux;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        Unit[] units_aux = (Unit[])value;
        this.list_units.Clear();
        foreach (Unit u in units_aux)
            this.lista_units.Add(u);
    }
}
```

I want to translate this to Java, but I have not been successful in translating it with no syntax errors. I'm very new to Java, so maybe this is a basic question, but i haven't found any information on how to do this that won't produce errors.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have a good answer here below, but next time you should probably post what you've done so far (the Java code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd basically have to convert it to a pair of methods:

```
public Unit[] getUnits() {
    // Method body
}

public void setUnits(Unit[] value) {
    // Method body
}
```

Java doesn't have properties at a *language* level - the above is basically just a (very common) convention.

I should note, by the way, that this C# code really isn't terribly nice:

- There are simpler ways of converting an array to a list and vice versa
- The setter *ignores* a null value when I'd expect it to throw an exception
- By cloning the array, it doesn't have the generally-expected behaviour (at least, my expectations) if you set the property and then modify the array contents. It's usually a bad idea to have an array as a property type anyway; if you could get away with making it a read-only collection, that would be nicer and make life *much* simpler.

Comment: In addition to that: Just write private Unit[]; and you'll be able to automatically generate getter and setter. In Eclipse: Source - "Generate Getters and Setters...". Guess other IDEs have the same feature.

Comment: @Feroc: Yes, although it won't be doing the same thing as the body of the existing C# code.

Comment: That's correct. But I hope he's able to fill the generated methods accordingly.

Comment: Your last bullet point at least arguable, if not totally wrong.

Comment: @talex: Well it's definitely not wrong from *my* perspective, in that it violates my expectations. Generally having a property which is an array is a nasty idea anyway.